# Save generated random numbers with numpy in dictionary

Tags: pandas, numpy, dictionary, random

I have a code that generates numbers using NumPy uniform distribution, but I want to save them in a dictionary.

```
x = [1391096.378,
9187722.876,
516012.8602,
238575.7104,
228114.5731,
4685929.962,
675871.7576,
2371583.637,
368942.1523,
39899030.28,
2068330.11,
2663072.562,
587247.8119,
2077461.753,
6620623.744,
246850.7431,
313607.552,
1108662.4,
250.7123965,
39.30786207,
1975239.413,
]

t = 0
for i in x: 
        s = i/31 
        a = (s + 0.2*s)
        b = (s - 0.2*s)
        dft = np.random.uniform(a,b,31)
        t =+1
```

But I don't know how to do that.

Comment: What should the keys of the dictionary be? Also, in the last line `t=+1` is doing `t = 1`, I think you mean `t+=1`.

Comment: The keys can be anything, no matter. About t =+1, yeah, I mean t +=1. Thanks for mention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the keys of the dictionary will be integers from 0 to 20. If you'd like to have the value of `x` as a key, then you can substitute the `t` with the `x`, like this: `stored[x] = dft`.

Or you can use [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) to be more creative with the dictionary's keys

```
t = 0
stored = {}

for i in x: 
    s = i/31 
    a = (s + 0.2*s)
    b = (s - 0.2*s)
    dft = np.random.uniform(a,b,31)
    stored[t] = dft
    t += 1
```